# Custom pycurl call

Tags: python, parameters, pycurl

I'm trying to implement push notifications. I can trigger notifications with this call that I need to make from python:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Thunder-Secret-Key: secret2" --data-ascii "\"Hello World\"" http://localhost:8001/api/1.0.0/key2/channels/mychannel/
```

This works ok from the command line.

First I tried using the subprocess, but it gave me this strange error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

So I gave up on that and I'm trying to use pycurl. But the problem is that I don't know what to do with -X and with --data-ascii options.

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','X-Thunder-Secret-Key: secret2'])
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost:8001/api/1.0.0/key2/channels/mychannel/')
c.perform()
print("Done")
```

So how do I add -X option and how do I send the text message with the request?

Comment: What operation system do you use and which version of curl(```curl -V```)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request, [see documentation example](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html#sending-form-data).

I think something like this should work (I've used python 2):

```
import pycurl    

c = pycurl.Curl()

postfields = '"Hello World"'
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/tests/testpostvars.php')
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','X-Thunder-Secret-Key: secret2'])
# Here we set data for POST request
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)

c.perform()
c.close()
```

This code produces following HTTP packet:

```
POST /tests/testpostvars.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PycURL/7.19.5.1 libcurl/7.37.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Host: pycurl.sourceforge.net
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
X-Thunder-Secret-Key: secret2
Content-Length: 13

"Hello World"
```

Comment: been looking for this answer for long, thanks, now I know my pycurl request is rejected for another reason.